# Parametric Equation - need help

Tags: parametric

I was wonder if anyone would be able to help me with this problem. I have done problems similar but the +3 is throwing me off in this problem. How would you make it into a rectangular equation?
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z93vI.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Take the time to enter critical parts of your questions as text using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions instead of linking to or pasting pictures of them. Your question is incomprehensible without that image and so is inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=\sin t + 3 \implies \sin^2 t = (x-3)^2$$

$$y=4\cos^2t = 4(1-\sin^2 t) = 4(1-(x-3)^2)$$

Hopefully you can do the simplification.